# registration form and sign in with jsp with netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I am trying to run jsp code making registration form and login and out and i have this problem 
I am using net beans and database mysql 
the error is:

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error type Exception report messageInternal Server Error descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jbdc.Driver root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jbdc.Driver note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

Class.forName("com.mysql.jbdc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/commerce","root","root");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jbdc.Driver");

int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into user(name,password,email,b_date,gender,country,job,address,credit) values ('" + user + "','" + pwd + "','" + email + "','" + b_date + "' , '" + gender + "','" + country + "','" + job + "','" + address + "','" + credit + "')");

you mean that this is worng

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not added `jdbc` driver . Refer [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jdbc-driver) for more info

Also [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) and [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html) to know how to add the jar file

Hope it helps!!